Repeat rows in Google Spreadsheet based on a cell value (BUT repeated rows must be 7 days apart)
I have a Google spreadsheet with two sheets: 'Input Sheet' and 'Output Sheet'. I would like all rows in the 'Input Sheet' to be repeated and stored in the 'Output Sheet' based on a cell value in column H.
I got the repeater to work with the following formula (formula is in cell A2 of the 'Output Sheet'):
=ARRAYFORMULA(
     VLOOKUP(
        TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(ROW('Input Sheet'!A2:A)&" ",'Input Sheet'!H2:H),,9^9)," ")),
        {ROW('Input Sheet'!A2:A),'Input Sheet'!A2:I},
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}+1,0
     )
)

However, in the 'Output Sheet', the values in columns F and G are just repeated based on the 'Input Sheet'. I would like column F and G values to be exact 1 week apart. For ex: cell F2 should be 4/7/2024 and cell G2 should be 4/13/2024. Cell F3 should be 4/14/2024 and cell G3 should be 4/20/2024, and so on...
A little help on how I can accomplish this please. Thank you!
I have included the spreadsheet below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14jxO12zW7SKe6e5TpmLA6nIdPjWP17XZtghGvWmgn1M/edit?usp=sharing
Including a visual for my current and desired results below:
> CURRENT:
Week (Start) |  Week (End)  | Weeks

Apr 7, 2024  | Apr 27, 2024 | 3 (row 1)
Apr 7, 2024  | Apr 27, 2024 | 3 (row 2)
Apr 7, 2024  | Apr 27, 2024 | 3 (row 3)

> DESIRED:
Week (Start)  |  Week (End)  | Weeks

Apr 7, 2024   | Apr 13, 2024 | 3 (row 1)
Apr 14, 2024  | Apr 20, 2024 | 3 (row 2)
Apr 21, 2024  | Apr 27, 2024 | 3 (row 3)


Can you showcase your ideal expected output by entering it manually?!

Yup absolutely, I have added that in my original question!

Can you showcase the whole output thing in your test sheet; not just a sample of it...

=LET(rng,'Input Sheet'!A2:I, 
   arr,FILTER(rng,INDEX(rng,,1)<>""),
   WRAPROWS(TOROW(BYROW(arr, LAMBDA(r, TOROW(
     MAP(SEQUENCE(INDEX(r,,8)), LAMBDA(wk, 
       {CHOOSECOLS(r, SEQUENCE(4)), INDEX(r,,6)+7*(wk-1),
        INDEX(r,,6)+7*wk-1, INDEX(r,,9)}))))),1),7))


First BYROW passes the array arr row by row into a LAMBDA that stores the current row in r.
That LAMBDA's formula is a MAP function that passes a SEQUENCE derived from the number of weeks into a LAMBDA that stores the current week in wk.
That LAMBDA's formula returns an array for each wk where:

The first 4 columns are the first 4 columns from r,
The fifth column is the week (start) value from r with wk-1 weeks added
The sixth column is the week (start) value with wk weeks added.
The seventh and last column is the hours from column 9 of r


Since the BYROW function requires the LAMBDA to return a single row for each row passed in, the MAP function is wrapped in TOROW.
The result of the BYROW is an array where each row represents a single row from arr, but the number of columns for each row can vary by multiples of 7.
To get an array of only 7 columns, TOROW is applied to the result with the skip_blanks argument included, then WRAPROWS is used to wrap that row every 7 columns.


Oh wow, thank you so much, you are absolutely brilliant!!! This helped me immensely!
I just made a small tweak to the formula to alter output for columns 5 and 6 in the 'Output Sheet' as I wanted the Start and End weeks to be 1 week apart from the initial and last week respectively. Here's my new formula!
=LET(rng,'Input Sheet'!A2:I,
arr,FILTER(rng,INDEX(rng,,1)<>""),
WRAPROWS(TOROW(BYROW(arr, LAMBDA(r, TOROW(
MAP(SEQUENCE(INDEX(r,,8)), LAMBDA(wk,
{CHOOSECOLS(r, SEQUENCE(4)), INDEX(r,,6)+7*(wk-1),
INDEX(r,,6)+7*wk-1, INDEX(r,,9)}))))),1),7))

Yes, it was a typo the column numbers for the weeks should have been 6, not 7, I have corrected them. I see what you mean about subtracting a day from the ending week calculation. Good catch wasn't thinking about that.
